# How to format irb command prompt

Tags: ruby, irb

Previously I was using Ruby 1.8 and my `irb` command prompt used to look like this:

```
Air ~: irb
>> a = 1
=> 1
>> b = 2
=> 2
>> a + b
=> 3
```

I installed rvm (and Ruby 1.9.2) and now my `irb` command prompt looks like this:

```
Air ~: irb
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > a = 1
 => 1 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > b = 2
 => 2 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > a + b
 => 3
```

Is there a way to remove the `ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001` from the command line?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/workflow/irbrc/ and http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/irb.html (linked from the first link)

Comment: for whatever reason adding a ~/.irbrc like most people are suggesting isn't working for me.  any other tips?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `irb` man page has a section on "[Customizing prompt](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html#module-IRB-label-Auto+indentation)". Here's mine for example:

```
IRB.conf[:PROMPT][:CUSTOM] = {
  :PROMPT_I => ">> ",
  :PROMPT_S => "%l>> ",
  :PROMPT_C => ".. ",
  :PROMPT_N => ".. ",
  :RETURN => "=> %s\n"
}
IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE] = :CUSTOM
IRB.conf[:AUTO_INDENT] = true
```

To use this, add it to your `~/.irbrc` file (creating it if it doesn't exist.)

Comment: [official link](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html#module-IRB-label-Auto+indentation) has more information.

Comment: Been using `pry` exclusively for a while now.

Answer (score 20):

In your `~/.irbrc`, simply add

```
IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE] = :SIMPLE
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work

Air ~: more .irbc 
IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE] = :SIMPLE
Air ~: irb
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > exit

Answer (score 9):

When you would usually run the `irb` command, try running `irb --simple-prompt` instead. That greatly shortens the prompt and makes it easier to understand.

Answer (score 4):

```
irb --simple-prompt
```

saw this in Lynda.com

Comment: Is able to initialization `--simple-prompt` on `~/irbc` ?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid giving the prompt you wish on the command line all the time, you can [configure the prompt via the `~/.irbrc` config file](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/irb.html):

```
$ echo "IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE] = :DEFAULT" > ~/.irbrc
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> quit
$ echo "IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE] = :SIMPLE" > ~/.irbrc
$ irb
>> quit
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Whoever want to add a prompt timestamp, this [isn't possible yet](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html#module-IRB-label-Customizing+the+IRB+Prompt) (check "special strings" section), so I implemented it in a monkey-patchy way:

```
module IrbTimePrompt
  def prompt(prompt, ltype, indent, line_no)
    # I used %T as time format, but you could use whatever you want to.
    # Check https://apidock.com/ruby/Time/strftime for more options
    p = prompt.dup.gsub(/%t/, Time.new.strftime('%T'))
    super(p, ltype, indent, line_no)
  end
end

module IRB
  class Irb
    prepend IrbTimePrompt
  end
end
```

Now, add this to your `lib/` project folder (in case is a Rails project, ensure `lib/` is part of `config.autoload_paths` in `config/application.rb`) or in a more aggresive way (not recommended), look for `lib/irb.rb` file in your local ruby instance and in [`def prompt`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/93ca212ddac5ac49134f2058c24db3948b6695c6/lib/irb.rb#L699-L736) method, add a new `when` condition to the method, like:

```
    when "t"
      Time.now.strftime('%-d-%-m %T%Z')
```

then in your `.irbrc` file (it could be located in your home folder or root project folder) you could modify your prompt. I'm adding my current prompt, but please adjust it to your needs:

```
def rails_prompt
  # This is my base prompt, displaying line number and time
  def_prompt = '[%01n][%t]'
  # Maybe you're only running as `irb` an not `rails console`, so check first
  # if rails is available
  if defined? Rails
    app_env = Rails.env[0...4]
    if Rails.env.production?
      puts "\n\e[1m\e[41mWARNING: YOU ARE USING RAILS CONSOLE IN PRODUCTION!\n" \
           "Changing data can cause serious data loss.\n" \
           "Make sure you know what you're doing.\e[0m\e[22m\n\n"
      app_env = "\e[31m#{app_env}\e[0m" # red
    else
      app_env = "\e[32m#{app_env}\e[0m" # green
    end
    def_prompt << "(\e[1m#{app_env}\e[22m)" # bold
  end

  IRB.conf[:PROMPT] ||= {}
  IRB.conf[:PROMPT][:WITH_TIME] = {
    PROMPT_I: "#{def_prompt}> ",
    PROMPT_N: "#{def_prompt}| ",
    PROMPT_C: "#{def_prompt}| ",
    PROMPT_S: "#{def_prompt}%l ",
    RETURN: "=> %s\n",
    AUTO_INDENT: true,
  }
  IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE] = :WITH_TIME
end

rails_prompt
```

Then start `irb` or `rails console` and check the awesomeness:

```
[1][13:01:15](deve)> 'say hello to your new prompt'
=> "say hello to your new prompt"
[2][13:01:23](deve)>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [note about IRB prompt](http://rvm.io/workflow/irbrc/) in RVM.

Note that you can create a `.irbrc` file in your home folder for various settings for IRB.
For example, see "Configuring the Prompt" in [this document](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/irb.html)

You can also `puts IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE]` or `puts IRB.conf` to see all the various settings currently in effect. For example, the `:PROMPT_MODE` is probably set to "RVM" in your case.