# Is it possible to automatically show timestamps in Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, irb, rails-console

After I start the Rails console, I see a prompt like this:

```
Loading production environment (Rails 4.x.y.z)
irb(main):001:0>
```

How can I customize Rails/irb such that each line, instead of showing `:001:0>`, shows something like `:001:0|2016-06-20T16:42:57-04:00>`?

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html should give you info on how to achieve that.

Comment: yeah, in the Customizing the IRB Prompt section of that page, to be more specific.

Comment: This is possible [monkey-patching `IRB::Irb` class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59996294/895789)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is actually possible to add the timestamp in based on the options that are available from the documentation.

[Another thread about similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039292/how-to-format-irb-command-prompt)

[Official Documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html#module-IRB-label-Auto+indentation)